# PHP retrieve data from another coloumn instead of id

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database and I want to retrieve data from it. the name of the table is "videos" and has 5 coloumns id,name,videolink,category,description.
In category there are 4 fixed values (music,movies,drama,dance) and on one page i only want to display movies from this table and I am using this code but all the videos are displaying on my webpage successfully. I only want to display data where the category is movies. I want the movies to be displayed with with names and descriptions etc. 
what should I change?

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "watchvideos.com");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$result = mysqli_query ($db, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<H3>".$row['name']."</H3>";
echo "<p>".$row['description']."";
echo "<iframe src=https://www.watchvideos.com/video1".$row['videolink']."></iframe>";   
}
?>
```

Comment: Any basic SQL tutorial will answer this question for you

Comment: Then add that in your query: `SELECT * FROM videos WHERE category = "movies"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to getting only the data which is related to movies , check the below code

Get only the data related to movie by changing the sql to the one below

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos where category='movies'";

 $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       echo "<H3>".$row['name']."</H3>";
       echo "<p>".$row['description']."";
       echo "<iframe src=https://www.watchvideos.com/video1".$row['videolink'].">
 </iframe>";


    }
```

For further reference please refer http://php.net/manual/en/index.php